# How can I make my tail animation smoother?

Tags: animation

Lately, I've been trying animating on blender, at this point I'm not even sure if I've mastered the basics but in an excited hurry to utilise blender's animation editor I created this choppy, inconsistent mess with a tail model I rigged and a few other unrefined works just like it:

[image]

It doesn't take a second glance at it to realise how awful it is. I'd like to make the animation more smooth and I'd greatly appreciate any tips/advice that would help me in doing so.

This is the dope sheet for the animation:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A smooth effect is extremely easy to create, utilizing interpolation in 3D animation. Make sure your bone chain is fully forward kinematic.

1. Set a key for both extreme position and copy the first extreme and insert it at the end again. This results in the two keyframes A > B > A'. I created the pose by switching to *Individual origins* so that I could rotate all of the bones at once. I created the inverse keyframe by <kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> pasting the pose.
   [image: two keys]
2. Make the animation repeat by pressing <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> in the dope sheet and selecting **Make Cyclic**.
   [image: Cyclic Repeat]
3. The child joints of a chain would move after their parent joints. This is what the **[overlapping action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Follow_through_and_overlapping_action)** principle of animation embodies. Grab the keyframes of the child bones and offset them one by one.
   [image: offsetting child joints]

---

- If you want more overlap (resulting in a snake-like action) increase the offset of the keys.
- If you want less overlap (resulting in a more stiff / rigid action, e.g. a dinosaurs tail) decrease the offset of the keys.
- If you want more movement in general, go to the graph editor and scale the curves along their Y axis.
- If some joints are shorter than other, their animation would likely have a smaller magnitude. This can be respected while setting the keys in the beginning.
- Adjacent shorter joints would also have less offset in timing than adjacent larger joints.